How to Center and Scale Images Proportionally in a PDF Using jspdf Without Quality Loss?
I want to display images within a PDF using jspdf, but I am facing an issue with how the images are being rendered.
Issue:
The image is covering the entire div in the PDF.
Desired Result:
The image should be placed at the center of the div, maintaining its aspect ratio without stretching or distorting.
The image should scale proportionally to fit within the available space, ensuring it does not stretch, compress, or lose quality.
The image should have some spacing from the container's border.
The images I work with come in various shapes, including rectangular, square, and near-square dimensions.
What I've Tried:
I followed this solution, and while it works for all cases,but it damages the image quality.
I also wrote the following code, but it doesn't fully address the issue:
Square images cover the entire div. Some images stretch or distort, while others render correctly.
I've included sample images to illustrate how I want my images to appear in the PDF. The red rectangle represents the container.



import { jsPDF as JsPDF } from 'jspdf';

function getDataUriFromImage(url: string, maxWidth = 800, quality = 0.7): Promise<string> {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    const image = new Image();

    image.onload = () => {
      const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
      const context = canvas.getContext('2d');

      const imageAspectRatio = image.naturalWidth / image.naturalHeight;

      const isSquare = Math.abs(imageAspectRatio - 1) < 0.1; 
      
      let canvasWidth = maxWidth;
      let canvasHeight = maxWidth /imageAspectRatio;
      
      if (isSquare) {
        canvasWidth = maxWidth;
        canvasHeight = maxWidth;
      } else {
        if (imageAspectRatio > 1) {
          canvasHeight = maxWidth / imageAspectRatio;
          canvasWidth = maxWidth;
        } else {
          canvasWidth = maxWidth * imageAspectRatio;
          canvasHeight = maxWidth;
        }
      }

      canvas.width = maxWidth;
      canvas.height = maxWidth;

      if (context) {
        context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

        const xOffset = (canvas.width - canvasWidth) / 2;
        const yOffset = (canvas.height - canvasHeight) / 2;

        context.drawImage(image, xOffset, yOffset, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
      }

      resolve(canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg", quality));
    };

    image.src = url;
  });
}

these styles work correctly in the browser. my problem is just for pdf.
<div class="col-6">
    <div class="w-100 h-100  image-container">
         <img  class="sample" />
     </div>
</div>

.image-container {
  background-color: black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  max-height: 185px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;

  img {
     width: auto;
    // max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    object-fit: contain;
  }
  .sample {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

